# Yet another character encoding issue

Tags: php, character-encoding

The language is Php. The editor is Php Storm. The editor encoding is utf-8. The file encoding also. `mb_detect_encoding()` also returns that the encoding is utf-8 but php does not recognizes č, ć, ž, đ and others. Does anyone know what the problem is?

I know that this is yet another character encoding question and that the solution is never clear in this case, but thank you for any answer.

EDIT

I use my own php framework and the index.php file is encoded to ANSI, not utf-8, but the rest of the files are utf-8. If I try to change from ANSI to utf-8, I get a content encoding
error.

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by "php does not recognize" the characters you mention?

Comment: what do you mean, "doesn't recognize"?

Comment: for example, č => Ä character, which probably means that it's using some other encoding but the mb_detect_encoding() return utf-8.

Comment: The file is also saved as utf-8 on windows, if that has any relevance

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with these lines of code:

```
ini_set('mbstring.internal_encoding','UTF-8');
ini_set( 'default_charset', 'UTF-8' );
ini_set('mbstring.func_overload',7);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Actually, setting the 'default_charset' is enough to work but since I spent the last 4 hours trying to solve this, the hell with it. Let it all fire.